# c# error on windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, installutil

I have the following error:

```
 OpenSCManager Failed 5: Access is denied.
```

Can someone help me? Is there another way besides using installutil to install the windows service ?

P.S : I am using Visual studio 2008. I did look for installutil in `C:\VisualStudio...` but i can't find it either.

I found the InstallUtil.exe executable. I run the application and now i have the error: c:...\InstallUtil,installLog is denied. WHY?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Are you a local admin?

Comment: i have all proprities on my computer.

Comment: @elisa, it should be in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework.  Best way to install a service.  However, you can also do it progmatically -- but if you have to ask, just don't try to.

Comment: Did you elevate before trying to install this service?

Comment: ok.thx i found it:). Can you tell me how can i access the installutil example if i have the path of this executable?

Comment: David what do you mean my elevate?

Comment: @elisa Under UAC admins run with a standard rights token. In order to gain admin rights token you elevate, run as administrator. You are au fait with UAC aren't you?

Comment: I do run the application as an administrator. so that is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here:

1. For the access denied problem. Chances are you are don't have permissions. Run the command with administrative privilegies. This means that you have to be a member of administrators group and your process has to be elevated, i.e. you have to right-click -> Run As Administrator to lauch the process.
2. There are many ways to install service. Since you already know InstallUtil, I don't have to mention it.

   - There is Win32 API called [CreateService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
   - There is command line utility [sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) -- it comes with OS by default
   - If you are so inclined, you can hack registry -- it is not that difficult to reverse engineer records under HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Service\

I personally prefer sc.exe. It installs managed services just fine.